# Email from GoDaddy is showing with 'via' in Gmail

Tags: php, email, cpanel

I have a PHP site hosted on GoDaddy, when I send an email from the site with an email on the same domain, it comes through to my gmail inbox, however the from field shows the from address I selected as well as the actual domain which it says is {id}.prod.secureserver.net

I have set up the email address that I want to use in cPanel, my understanding is that if I did this then when I send the email with PHP GoDaddy would send the email directly from my domain email. However, it shows as coming via secureserver.net

Comment: Gmail seems to show that on a lot of mails, not sure your server is at at fault specifically. Have you done any research about it?

Comment: Is your PHP app connecting to the email server via SMTP or IMAP to send the email? If you are just using the web server via `mail()` or a library that uses the basic `mail()` function, it is still being sent directly from the web server.

Comment: Review the source code of the received email. Do you use Google Workspace? Don't you have DNS records set up for email to be handled by Google?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved this. You have to send using credentials, not just pipe to SMTP. Create a mail account on cPanel that matches the "From" address you want to use. Save the full email address and password. Then in your PHP application, set the SMTP server to the one given in the cPanel email setup (it is NOT mail-relay.secureserver.net or anything like that - it will be yourdomain.com or subdomain.yourdomain.com if you've set this up on a subdomain - this is critical because secureserver.net will not respond on port 465 but your domain will).

The port is 465, the protocol is SMTPS (not STARTTLS), and the from address and username are the email address you created (obviously use the same password - the authentication is login or plain). I just set this up in our Wordpress installation on GoDaddy and now I pass SPF and my emails no longer show "via secureserver.net".

Comment: Thank you. I have set up the email on cPanel. Should the host be secureserver.net or my domain? When I use my domain I do get through but I get SMTP Error: data not accepted.SMTP server error: DATA END command failed Detail: This message was classified as SPAM and may not be delivered (when I use secureserver.net I don't get through at all).

Comment: Ignore the above, it all works now. The line "it is NOT mail-relay.secureserver.net or anything like that - it will be yourdomain.com or subdomain.yourdomain.com if you've set this up on a subdomain" was the line that did it for me. I had set everything up in cPanel but was still using secureserver.net for my host value I'll mark this as the answer

Comment: I am using Google Workspace for my emails . So Icreated  all mail account there, but in GoDaddy I have de host and domain? 

Sending email from my website to gmail.com works, but when I tray to send it to  mydomain.com it send me a error

Comment: This worked for me after years of trying to find an *effective and reliable* solution for sending from a Wordpress installation on a Godaddy server (using WP Mail SMTP lite). As long as you have access to cPanel on your GoDaddy account, this method should work for you. Thank you, haus!

Comment: does it work only for cPanel?